# Where is `__atomic_compare_exchange` defined in the g++ source?

Tags: c++, atomic

In the g++ source code under the file `/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic` in my system, the function `atomic::compare_exchange_strong` has the following body.

```
  bool
  compare_exchange_strong(_Tp& __e, _Tp __i, memory_order __s, 
              memory_order __f) noexcept
  {
return __atomic_compare_exchange(&_M_i, &__e, &__i, false, __s, __f); 
  }
```

However, this file includes only `bits/atomic_base.h` and I did not find a definition for `__atomic_compare_exchange` in this file.

Where is `__atomic_compare_exchange` defined?

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/03a400fb461fdc020418f3841d446f565e208db3/gcc/builtins.c#L5091

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__atomic_compare_exchange` is a compiler builtin. It's not actually defined in the headers anywhere -- the compiler itself knows what it is.

In the GCC source itself, it's declared in [sync-builtins.def](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/sync-builtins.def#L313). I'm not familiar with GCC's source, so I'm not sure exactly how that percolates down to architecture-specific implementations (though it seems likely to pass through [maybe_emit_atomic_exchange](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/optabs.c#L5812)), but the source of e.g. x86 instructions representing it can be found in another platform-specific generator file named [sync.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/master/gcc/config/i386/sync.md):

```
(define_insn "atomic_exchange<mode>"
  [(set (match_operand:SWI 0 "register_operand" "=<r>")     ;; output
    (unspec_volatile:SWI
      [(match_operand:SWI 1 "memory_operand" "+m")      ;; memory
       (match_operand:SI 3 "const_int_operand")]        ;; model
      UNSPECV_XCHG))
   (set (match_dup 1)
    (match_operand:SWI 2 "register_operand" "0"))]      ;; input
  ""
  "%K3xchg{<imodesuffix>}\t{%1, %0|%0, %1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a compiler intrinsic - something the compiler itself takes and works with as opposed to being a pure library solution. Some compiler help is necessary in order to implement the full standard library, such as some type traits, and in other cases, the compiler can do a much better job, like in `std::make_index_sequence`, which has more recently been getting this treatment in order to perform well for non-small values.